LyLuaTeX warning: “gs couldn't be launched; there could be rounding error”
I tried compiling the following LuaTeX document using lualatex --shell-escape:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass-fonts]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
  a b c d
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}

Then I get the following warning:

Module lyluatex Warning: gs couldn't be launched; there could be rounding error
s. on input line 9

Recompiling, the warning is gone. But it reappears whenever I edit something in the Lilypond notation. I tried googling the error, but literally nothing came up.

well it is not an error but a warning. Obviously ghostscript is missing and a fallback is used. See also the note on page 16 in the documentation.
